# Problemas de inserción de datos Android Studio MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, base-de-datos

Hice la conexión y pruebas correspondiente en mi navegador con el archivo PHP, pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación e ingresar los datos me sale el mensaje de que se agregó sin problemas pero consulto a la BD y no hay nada ingresado, probé sacando la URL que ven y la app se cae lógicamente, pero pongo cualquier URL y me sale el mensaje de que se insertó, a que se debe el problema?

El código lo hice tal cual un tutorial que vi pero no encuentro la razón de que falle, como dije anteriormente, probé el archivo php y me funcionó bien insertando datos desde el navegador.

Como dato ya di los permisos para conexión a internet.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            new CargarDatos().execute("http://192.168.1.36:7777/PruebaAS/registro.php?correo=" + tCorreo.getText().toString() + "&nombre=" + tNombre.getText().toString() + "&contrasena=" + tPass.getText().toString() + "&fecha=" + tFecha.getText().toString());

        }
    });
}


private class CargarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "No se puede recuperar la página web. La URL puede ser inválida.";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se almacenaron los datos correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    //Conexion MYSQL
    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        Log.i("URL", "" + myurl);
        myurl = myurl.replace(" ", "%20");
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("respuesta", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, te recomendaría algo más robusto para hacer inserciones a base de datos, como pudiera ser Webservice rest, la forma de consumirlos y hasta realizarlos es bastante sencillo Hay muchas páginas que lo mencionan. 
https://gist.github.com/jhbsk/4340088

¿Por qué lo digo? los espacios en una petición http se deben escapar así como caracteres especiales además se ve bastante feo una petición de inserción en un método GET, cambialo a POST en caso de que no quisieras usar un webservice.

y para resolver tu problema te sugiero utilizar
URLEncoder.encode(tuURL, "UTF-8");

Respuesta sacada desde esta página.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

También pudiera ser que no tengas permiso desde el PHP (apache, IIS, etc) para que se vea desde fuera de localhost.

Comment: Concuerdo bastante con la respuesta, lo más recomendable sería manejar la BD mediante un API Restfull, luego con ayuda de librerías como GSON y Retrofit el llamado de la misma no supone un mayor problema.